# Chrysler minivan second row seat heater turns itself off immediately

Tags: chrysler, town-and-country

I have a 2012 Chrysler Town & Country with heated second row stow-and-go seats. The seat heater for the driver-side second-row seat no longer works. When the button is pushed, it illuminates and there's a click from the dashboard. Within two seconds, there's another click from the dashboard and it turns back off completely. Both front seats and the passenger-side second-row seat work correctly. All the fuses seem to be good.

Where do I start diagnosing this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not completely fluent in how these works, but it sounds like there's a short in the heating element which is overpowering the relay which turns it on. This would cause it to switch off as you describe.